# Get height of PHP-generated div with pure javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic, height, division

I have been trying to calculate the height of a division which I generated using PHP-MySQL and can't find anything that works. I'd really like to do it in pure javascript since I don't get on with jQuery at all. I tried element.style.height and element.style.height() and also element.style.offsetHeight and even element.currentStyle (or window.getComputedStyle for W3C browsers).

Yet nothing works. There are a lot of posts but none of the advice seems to work. I really don't know what to try any more...please don't suggest a jQuery solution since I just tried $('#element').height() and $('#element').outerHeight(), and neither worked. Is it actually possible? The division is output as a series of commands such as

```
echo ('<div id="myDiv">...</div>');
```

I hope someone can help me with this, it's brought me to a complete standstill.

Comment: It really doesn't matter whether the div was "generated" with PHP, or written by hand. There is no difference in how the browser treats it, and indeed, the browser never gets to know the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate: Pretty much any question with [these search terms.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+height+element)

Answer (score 3):

`element.offsetHeight` - the offset height is not a part of the style information.

Comment: A link as well for some reading:): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetHeight also you'll most likely need to wait until `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

[element.clientWidth](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmclkbi.php) might also be useful.